# Which is best loop to fetch data from a Cusor in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am learning Oracle PL/SQL. I want to know that which loop is best for fetching the data from a Cursor. And also please tell me that when should i use which loop for best performance.

Comment: What all loops do you know about?

Comment: I mean basic loop or for loop?

Comment: Every part of a programming language has some utility or some flavour which makes it usable in some/other situations. It depends on the problem you want to solve or on your preference. For example, simple `loop` being better than a `for loop` is an absurd discussion.

Answer (score 3):

I would rather avoid using an **explicit cursor** and use a **cursor for loop**.

For example,

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN
  (SELECT column_list FROM table
  )
  LOOP
    <do something>
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Remember, a loop would do it **row-by-row** a.k.a. **slow-by-slow**.

Also, there is a reason why the `cursor for loop` is better over the explicit cursor. In the recent Oracle versions, it is optimized in a better way by doing a `bulk collect limit 100` internally.

But, it's not just about **bulk collecting**, we are dealing with the **operations** we would subsequently do on the array that we have **fetched** incrementally. We could further improve the performance by using **FORALL** statement along with **BULK COLLECT**.

IMO, if it is possible, then do it in pure **SQL**. Because, SQL and PL/SQL are two different engines. All procedural code is handled by the PL/SQL engine while all SQL is handled by the SQL statement executor, or SQL engine. There is an overhead associated with each **context switch** between the two engines. So, if possible avoid context switching by doing it in pure SQL.

Comment: thanks for the valuable information.

Comment: @SPGuar Please mark it as answered, would help others too!